# iphone : problem while fetching tweets from twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, twitter

In my iphone app, I am trying to fetch tweets from twitter.

And I got one example coding from following link :

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

But when i implemented this example I got following warning:

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo.app/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo normal i386
 cd "/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo"
  setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
 setenv PATH      "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk "-L/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-L/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo/Libraries & Headers/OAuthConsumer" "-L/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo" "-F/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo/build/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo.build/Objects-normal/i386/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lOAuth -lsqlite3 -lxml2 -o "/Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo.app/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo"

ld: in /Volumes/MacShare/ANKIT BACKUP/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/aral-XAuthTwitterEngine-8713a93/XAuthTwitterEngineDemo/libxml2.dylib, file too small
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

What can be done?

Comment: can you correctly see the SDK which is currently selected? It should be in the top-left popup menu of your xcode project... does is say: "No Base SDK"?

Comment: @sergio: I can see the SDK properly. It is iOS 4.2. So it is not a problem related to "No Base SDK". What else could be wrong?

Comment: you should provide the full compiler output, that you can get in your build results window... "compiler failed with exit code 1" is a really generic error...

Comment: @sergio: I have posted the full compiler output. Please check it out

Comment: please, see my answer below... the problem is the xcode project is linking against a MacOS version of libxml2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch tweets from this [url](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=yummydietfood&count=75) and it returns `xml` from which you can parse tweets.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having lays with the fact that the MGTwitterEngine project is meant for Cocoa, so it links frameworks and libraries that are MacOS-only binaries. Specifically they are: libxml2 and AppKit.

In order to port this to iOS, you should create a new iOS project, import all the source code, and link to UIKit (this should already be ok) and to the iOS version of libxml2 (which you find when you do "add existing framework")....